# Shalach Manos $$$

Tags: purim, money, mishloach-manot

Can you use Money for Shalach Manos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it seems everyone thought it was A joke it seems the 
**SHUT Halachos Katanos חלק ב' סימן קס''ג** found it to be a serious question he adresses not only money but Clothing and Keilim (Kesus Vkailim)and says in a last case scenario where you can sell the item received for (Clothing)  or use it to pay for food (Money) right away for the Purim Seudah it works.

He bring two "Proofs" one from a Mishnah in Nedarim Lamed Beis Amud Beis:

אין בין מודר הנאה 
מחבירו למודר מאכל אלא דריסת הרגל

So he says you see from here that there is no difference between enjoyment that gets you to food(money) to food. He brings a second proof I am unsure what his proof is here from a gemarah in Megilah Daf Zayin amud Beis:

רב מרי שלח לרבה זנגבילא ופלפלי
He supposes they where dried out and hence not able to be eaten so he uses this as a second proof that an enjoyment that will bring to food is like food and therfore you have fulfilled your obligation of Shalach Manos
Lesson Learnt Never Jump to conclusions!!!!