# Frozen mishloach manos

Tags: halacha, mishloach-manot

I have learned (don't remember sources offhand) that raw food is not preferable for mishloach manos, because it isn't edible.

I was wondering if the same would apply to giving frozen food as mishloach manos.

My reason for wondering is that, on the one hand it would be the same as raw food in that the recipient cannot eat it as it is received. But on the other hand, he doesn't have to do anything to it to make it edible - just wait and it will be edible.

My question is both if it will defrost by the end of the day of Purim or even if it won't.

I already asked my Rabbi and got my answer, so this isn't a practical question - I am only interested to try and find sources who discuss it. My googling attempts came up dry.

Comment: "I already asked my Rabbi and got my answer". Huh??? If you have the answer, already, why don't you post your own (or, rather, your rabbi's) answer?

Comment: @DanF Because my personal Rabbi of our small local shul is probably not an authoritative source that most people would be interested in.

Comment: That may be personal opinion, but OK. Why not, at least, summarize his opinion in your question, then? It may offer some insight as to where he may have been getting the info from.

Comment: @DanF His answer was "I think it's fine." I don't imagine that would be very helpful.

Comment: Have a look at the 2nd part of this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6457/5275. I don't have time to view the original Gemarah source. But, it seems to indicate that non-edible food may be fine.

Comment: See Mishnah Berurah sf #20 on O.C. 595. The end of it has an opinion stating that raw meat may be acceptable since it has been slaughtered and is ready to be cooked. It's possible that this same logic could be used for most frozen foods, esp. already cooked foods that are just frozen. I would think that most frozen fruits and veggies are in this category.

Comment: @DanF I'm not sure what your point is. The OP said it's "not preferable" to send raw food, and is asking a question based on that opinion. His assumption that it is not "preferable" is corroborated by the fact that there is an opinion that says one should not send raw food. Answering based on that which there is _another_ opinion which permits it is missing the point.

Comment: @Yez I disagree. I realize that OP mentioned a preference. But, his main question asks if one is allowed to do something. Therefore, even "another" opinion that allows something, satisfies that criteria.

Comment: @DanF No. He said raw food is not preferable, and asked "if the same would apply." I don't see how you can possibly see that as asking anything other than if the problem with raw applies to frozen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This website](http://kehila.info/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/) (Chabad) says specifically that a frozen food that cannot be eaten as is, is not good for Mishloach Manos.  The source quoted is the Mishna Berura 695:19, which does not say anything about it specifically, but does mention the general rule of edible food.  I'm not sure this website is the authoritative source that you are looking for, though.

Rav Mordechai Eliyahu's summary [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/5687) may indicate that it would apply equally to frozen food (however, a frozen chicken may just not be cooked, h/t to DoubleAA):

> ולא יאמר אדם לחברו שהוא מעדיף שישלח לו עוף קפוא, אלא ישלח לו עוף מבושל דווקא שיהיה ראוי לאכילה מיידית‏

Rav Avraham Yosef [here](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=188048) rules that a frozen Pizza would count as one of the two foods needed for Mishloach Manos.